# Generic closure in protocol

Tags: generics, swift

I'd like to use a generic closure in a protocol. For example:

```
protocol Fetcher {

    func fetchWithSuccess<T>(success doSuccess : (T) -> (), failure doFailure : ((NSError?) -> ()))

}
```

I thought implementing such a protocol would work something like this:

```
class SimpleFetcher<T> : Fetcher {

    let thing : T

    init(thing : T) {
        self.thing = thing
    }

    func fetchWithSuccess<T>(success doSuccess : (T) -> (), failure doFailure : ((NSError?) -> ())) {
        doSuccess(self.thing) // Fails
    }
}
```

However, the above code fails with error `'T' is not convertible with 'T'` in `doSuccess(self.thing)`. What am I missing?

Might be worth mentioning that when using a class there is no problem:

```
class Fetcher<T> {

    func fetchWithSuccess(success doSuccess : (T) -> (), failure doFailure : ((NSError?) -> ())) {}

}

class SimpleFetcher<T> : Fetcher<T> {

    let thing : T

    init(thing : T) {
        self.thing = thing
    }

    override func fetchWithSuccess(success doSuccess : (T) -> (), failure doFailure : ((NSError?) -> ())) {
        doSuccess(self.thing)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 things to fix:

**Do not make the method generic, because the class is already using generics**

The class already defines the `T` generic type - if you use `<T>` in the method, the `T` type has no relationship with the type defined at class level - that explains why you have such a strange error message `T is not convertible to T`. To verify that, just change the generic name in the function from `T` to something else.

So your function should look like:

```
func fetchWithSuccess(success doSuccess : (T) -> (), failure doFailure : ((NSError?) -> ())) {
    doSuccess(self.thing) // Fails
}
```

**Define a type alias in the protocol**

You also have to define a type alias in the protocol, which is conceptually similar to generics for classes and structs (read [Type Alias Declaration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-XID_592) and [Protocol Associated Type Declaration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-XID_676))

```
protocol Fetcher {
    typealias V
    func fetchWithSuccess(success doSuccess : (V) -> (), failure doFailure : ((NSError?) -> ()))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two changes you need to make -- one in your protocol and one in your class.

In the protocol, define a `typealias` for the associated type, and have your method use that alias as the type. The methods in a generic class don't need to be generic themselves -- the methods use the generic type of the class itself.

```
protocol Fetcher {
    typealias Element

    func fetchWithSuccess(success doSuccess : (Element) -> (), failure doFailure : ((NSError?) -> ()))
}
```

Then in your class, declare that `typealias` to be `T`, and remove the generic syntax from the method:

```
class SimpleFetcher<T> : Fetcher {
    typealias Element = T

    let thing : T

    init(thing : T) {
        self.thing = thing
    }

    func fetchWithSuccess(success doSuccess : (T) -> (), failure doFailure : ((NSError?) -> ())) {
        doSuccess(self.thing) // Fails
    }
}
```

Testing:

```
let s = SimpleFetcher(thing: "Hello")
s.fetchWithSuccess(success: { str in println(str) }, failure: { error in println(error) })
// "Hello"
```

Comment: Great! This would create lots of architectural possibilities.